# Prime Number Theorem Related functions Divisibility Relation Counter Sought

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

In looking at the two functions defined:
$$\psi_{{0}}(x)=\ln( \operatorname{lcm}(1,2,3,...,\lfloor x \rfloor))$$

$$\psi_{{1}}(x)=\sum _{j=1}^{ \lfloor x \rfloor }  \sum _{i=0}^{ \Bigl\lfloor {\frac {\ln  \left( x \right) }{\ln  \left( p_{{j}}
 \right) }} \Bigr\rfloor +1}\ln  \left( {p_{{j}}}^{i}   \right) 
$$
(where $p_n$ is the $n^{th}$ prime and $lcm$ denontes the lowest common multiple of the arguments enclosed)

I am interested in finding the minimum value (if it exists) of $n \in \mathbb N$ that satisfies:

$$  {\Biggl\{\frac{\left(\lfloor \ln  \left(  \psi_{{0}}(n)+\psi_{{1}}(n)\right) 
 \rfloor +1 \right) !}{\lfloor \sqrt n \rfloor!}}\Biggr\} \ne 0$$

where ${\{x}\}$ denotes the fractional part of $x$.

some values evaluated:
$$\frac{\left(\lfloor \ln  \left(  \psi_{{0}}(8)+\psi_{{1}}(8)\right) 
 \rfloor +1 \right) !}{\lfloor \sqrt 8 \rfloor!}=12$$
$$\frac{\left(\lfloor \ln  \left(  \psi_{{0}}(12)+\psi_{{1}}(12)\right) 
 \rfloor +1 \right) !}{\lfloor \sqrt 12 \rfloor!}=20$$

$$\frac{\left(\lfloor \ln  \left(  \psi_{{0}}(20)+\psi_{{1}}(20)\right) 
 \rfloor +1 \right) !}{\lfloor \sqrt 20 \rfloor!}=5$$

The value is less than 1 at $n=36$ indicating this to be the immeadiate border of the   region of $\mathbb N$  for which the inequality Carl mentioned begins to be true (inductively reasoning).

Beyond $0<n<32$ I am not as yet able to produce a result, float approximations continue to imply that the value is 0 up  to $n=40$, however really what is needed here is someone with more experience in number theory to assess the situation and give an opinion as to whether it is worth pursuing or not.[image]

Closely related to the relations in a previous questions I posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2814343/finding-a-better-approximation-to-a-prime-number-relation) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2814472/counter-example-for-a-divisibility-relation)

I will try my best to follow along with Carl's answer, he has skipped a few steps that are probably what he may consider too obvious to show, but so far:
Because:
$$\psi_{{0}}(x)=\ln(\operatorname{lcm}(1,2,3,...,x-1,\lfloor x\rfloor))=\alpha\,\ln  \left( 2 \right) +\beta\,\ln  \left( 3 \right)... +\sum _{j=
1}^{ \lfloor x \rfloor }\ln  \left( p_{{j}} \right) 
$$ for some $$\alpha, \beta,... \in \mathbb N$$

And similarly:

$$\psi_{{1}}(x)=\sum _{j=1}^{ \lfloor x \rfloor }  \sum _{i=0}^{ \Bigl\lfloor {\frac {\ln  \left( x \right) }{\ln  \left( p_{{j}}
 \right) }} \Bigr\rfloor +1}\ln  \left( {p_{{j}}}^{i}   \right) =\frac{1}{2}\sum _{j=1}^{ \lfloor x \rfloor }\ln  \left( p_{{j}}
 \right)  \left(  \Bigl\lfloor {\frac {\ln  \left( x \right) }{
\ln  \left( p_{{j}} \right) }} \Bigr\rfloor +2 \right)  \left(  \Bigl\lfloor {\frac {\ln  \left( x \right) }{\ln  \left( p_{{j}} \right) }}
 \Bigr\rfloor +1 \right)$$
$$=\alpha'\,\ln  \left( 2 \right) +\beta'\,\ln  \left( 3 \right)... +\sum _{j=
1}^{ \lfloor x \rfloor }\ln  \left( p_{{j}} \right) $$
 for some $$\alpha', \beta',... \in \mathbb N$$

The asymptotic relation I think I originally started from, which   think is actually false as I originally stated, but again, just curious about the division relation on the naturals I really am new to asymptotics:

$$\sum _{j=1}^{ \lfloor x \rfloor } \left(  \Bigl\lfloor 
{\frac {\ln  \left( x \right) }{\ln  \left( p_{{j}} \right) }}
 \Bigr\rfloor +1 \right) \ln  \left( p_{{j}} \right)+\psi_{{0}}(x) \sim  x
$$
[image]

Comment: What is the source of this problem? Also, if I'm not mistaken, you're just asking for when $\lfloor \ln(\psi_0(n)+\psi_1(n))\rfloor < \lfloor \sqrt{n}\rfloor$, right?

Comment: That's correct yes. It arose from when I was studying the Chebyshev functions and asymptotic relations in prime number theory, after referred to do so after posting another question here.

Comment: If you can show me how to establish the bounds for that inequality, it would also be helpful I think, it was my impression they both increased without bound (denominator and numerator) and

Comment: Well not entirely sir, as I said it arose from when I was studying the Chebyshev functions, so it was a variation of those in trying to reproduce in a manner that I could compute numerical data from. I suppose if I changed any part it may not hold the same divisibility relation

Comment: I can't prove it, but it looks like $\psi_1(n)\sim \psi_0(n)\sim n$ (the second one follows from the prime number theorem but I can't prove the first yet).

Comment: I added a plot that I think confirms what you are saying

Comment: The first part of what you have said looks to be very much true from: $$\Bigl\lfloor \frac{\max(\psi_0(n),\psi_1(n))}{\min(\psi_0(n),\psi_1(n))}\Bigr\rfloor=1,1,1,1,1,1...$$

Comment: I am very sure they can be related to one another as the actual Chebyshev functions are with one another somehow.

Comment: Is there a reason for the double sum in the function $\psi_1$?  Starting from $i=0$ instead of $i=1$ seems unnecessary, so the expression doesn't seem to have a clear intent.  Contrary to Carl's comment, I believe the double sum causes $\psi_1(n)$ to be asymptotic to $\tfrac12 n \log n$ rather than $n$.

Comment: @ErickWong I believe I have now proven that $\psi(n)\sim 3n$, but it's possible I made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: No you are correct @Erick Wong, it is unnecessary, it's just my naivety and or laziness that's to blame there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As

$$\psi_0(x)=\sum_{p^i\leq x}\ln(p),$$

we have

\begin{align}
\psi_0(x)+\psi_1(x)
&=\sum_{p\leq x}\left[\lfloor\log_p(x)\rfloor\ln(p)+\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor\log_p(x)\rfloor+1}i\ln(p)\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{p\leq x}\ln(p)\left[\lfloor\log_p(x)\rfloor^2+5\lfloor\log_p(x)\rfloor+2\right]\\
&=\vartheta(x)+3\psi_0(x)+\frac{1}{2}\left[\sum_{p\leq \sqrt{x}} \ln(p)\left(\lfloor \log_p(x)\rfloor^2-\lfloor \log_p(x)\rfloor\right)\right]\\
&=\vartheta(x)+3\psi_0(x)+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{p\leq \sqrt{x}} \ln(p)\lfloor \log_p(x)\rfloor\left(\lfloor \log_p(x)\rfloor-1\right)\\
&\leq \vartheta(x)+3\psi_0(x)+\frac{\lfloor \log_2(x)\rfloor-1}{2}\sum_{p\leq \sqrt{x}} \ln(p)\lfloor \log_p(x)\rfloor\\
&= \vartheta(x)+3\psi_0(x)+\frac{\lfloor \log_2(x)\rfloor-1}{2}\psi_0(\sqrt{x})\\
&\leq \vartheta(x)+3\psi_0(x)+\log(x)\psi_0(\sqrt{x}).
\end{align}

As $\psi_0(x)\sim x$ by the Prime Number Theorem, this is asymptotic to

$$4x+c\sqrt{x}\log(x),$$

so

$$\log(\psi_0(x)+\psi_1(x))\sim \log(4x) << \sqrt{x}.$$

As your condition is

$$\lfloor \ln(\psi_0(n)+\psi_1(n))\rfloor < \lfloor \sqrt{n}\rfloor,$$

this is true for all sufficiently large $n$.

---

We claim that, for all $n>100$,

$$\ln(\psi_0(n)+\psi_1(n)) + 1 < \sqrt{n}.$$

Indeed, we already know

$$\psi_0(n)+\psi_1(n) \leq \vartheta(x)+3\psi_0(x)+\log(x)\psi_0(\sqrt{x});$$

using bounds from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function) we have that

$$\psi_0(x)+\psi_1(x)\leq 1.000028x+3\cdot 1.03883x+1.03883\left(\log(x)\sqrt{x}\right);$$

as

$$\frac{1}{2}\log(x)=\log(\sqrt{x})\sqrt{x}\leq x,$$

we then have

$$\psi_0(x)+\psi_1(x)\leq (4.116518)x+(2\cdot 1.03883)x < 7x.$$

So, we only need to prove that

$$\ln(7x)+1<\sqrt{x} \Leftrightarrow 0<\sqrt{x}-1-\ln(7x)$$

for $x>100$. At $x=100$, this is true. Its derivative is

$$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}-\frac{\ln(7)}{x}=\frac{1}{2x}\left(\sqrt{x}-2\ln(7)\right),$$

which is $>0$ if $x>4\ln(7)^2$, which is true for all $x>100$. This finishes the proof.

I have numerically verified that your condition is true for all $n\geq 25$ but no $n\leq 24$ using the following code:

```
def psi_sum(n):
    prod=1
    for p in sympy.ntheory.primerange(1,n+1):
        n2=n
        k=-1
        while n2>0:
            n2//=p
            k+=1
        v=(k**2+5*k+2)//2
        prod*=(p**v)
    return prod

f=lambda n:int(log(log(psi_sum(n))))
g=lambda n:int(sqrt(n))
print([n for n in range(2,101) if f(n)<g(n)])
```

Comment: Wow! It may take me some time to see how you were able to change things to a single sum

Comment: Sorry can you please teach me how you are able to assert it to be true for all $n$ greater than or equal to 25, I have no troubles with the first 25,it's confidence beyond I can't do!

Comment: I don't know it exactly, but I've checked it numerically through $100$. Later today I'll have more time to use explicit bounds on this - I should be able to prove it for all $n>100$ analytically.

Comment: I'm sorry sir don't you mean $n$ up to 100, rather than beyond 100?

Comment: @Adam This should be a complete answer now; see my latest edits.

Comment: ok no problem I think I am starting to see how this goes I spat the dummy with this last month because I couldn't find a proof for that square root relation between the Chebyshev functions I think you use

Answer (score 0):

$n=36$ is the answer to my original question

$$  {\Biggl\{\frac{\left(\lfloor \ln  \left(  \psi_{{0}}(36)+\psi_{{1}}(36)\right) 
 \rfloor +1 \right) !}{\lfloor \sqrt 36 \rfloor!}}\Biggr\}  =\frac{1}{6}$$